# How to get the user to input data until they enter quit then the system displays all the inputted data

Tags: java

Does anybody know why there in an error with this piece of code?

```
for ( int i=0; i<99; i++)
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print ("Please Enter Game Name: Achievement Score: Minutes Played ");

    Input1=scan.nextLine();
    if (Input1.compareTo("quit"))
        break;
```

Comment: It doesn't compile as `compareTo` doesn't return a `boolean` Try using `equals` instead. I suggest you read the error message and if you don't know what it means, include it in the question. I also suggest you improve your formatting using your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

`compareTo()` is used to compare numbers.
To compare text, you want to use `equals()`.

e.g.
`if (Input1.equals("quit"))`

Answer (score 0):

Use .equals() to compare the two strings. If you would like to compare the two strings regardless of the case you could use .equalsIgnoreCase(). The code below will take in values and store them in an ArrayList, when the user types quit the results that are stored in the ArrayList are presented to the user.

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input;
    ArrayList<String> inputValues = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++) {
        System.out.print("Please Enter Game Name... ");
        input = scan.nextLine();
        if(input.equals("quit")) {
            if(inputValues.size() == 0) {
                System.out.println("\nNo values have been entered");
            } else {
                System.out.println("\n******* Inputted Data *******");
                for (String anInputText : inputValues) {
                    System.out.println("Game Name " + anInputText);
                }
            }
            break;
        } else {
            inputValues.add(input);
        }
    }
}
```